# How to get the computer name in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hostname

I create a batch file with:

```
%computername% > %computername%.txt
```

It works great and creates the text file with computer name.
But how to create the same in PowerShell?

Different codes do not work, or my ideas are wrong. Only the computer name is in the text file but I wish to use the computer name for my text file if I don't know the name.

I tried:

```
Hostname >> .txt
```

But this writes the hostname in a file named `.txt`.
Next try:

```
$env:computername > $env:computername.txt
```

But this does nothing.

I don't know what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. This writes a text file  in the desired path.
To get the path of the current directory, use the wildcard `.\`.
Here it is:

```
$hn = Hostname 
new-item .\$hn.txt 
$hn >> .\$hn.txt
```

1. Create variable
2. Create a text file
3. Write to the text file

My problem is I tried all scripts without wildcard for path.